# Three potential db designs

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design

I've been considering three similar database designs, but haven't come up with a very strong for or against regarding any of them.

1. One huge table for content

   ```
   content: int id, enum type, int parent_id, varchar title, text body, text data
   ```

   This would assign each row a type (news, blog, etc), and have fields for common/standard/searchable data, then any non-standard or trivial data is stored as serialized xml in the `data` field.
2. One table for ids, many tables for content

   ```
   ids: int id, enum tableName, int parent_id
   ```

   This has one large table for ids, then every other table references this id, making it easy to have hierarchical content.
3. A combination of the two above, where a main table stores all common info, but unimportant data is stored in a respective table.

Naturally it's easier to keep data consistent when everything has its own table, but the above ideas make it much easier to force standardization of common fields, and makes it a lot simpler to relate content to eachother (especially with tagging).

Any thoughts or links would be appreciated.

Comment: Reading your question gives me very little understanding of what you're trying to store in this database, and what you intend to do with it. If you can help us understand those, we'll be in a better position to help you find an answer.

Comment: How often will the database be updated with data?  How large would you expect the tables to become?

Comment: @lansinwd: Updates would be infrequent since this would mostly be static content. If I stored comments in this table, the writing might be more frequent, but not by a large degree. As far as size, I'd like to explore how it performs compared to the others with 100k rows, 1m rows, and 5-10m rows or more.

Comment: @Matt Miller: This would be primarily for static content like news or blogs, and -maybe- comments. #2 would have an id for everything, though, including comments, tags, users, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea of a master lookup table with secondary tables for actual content is the best solution.  Drupal has a similar structure to what you describe and it has proven quite flexible.

```
http://projects.contentment.org/blog/84
```

Drupal has a main "node" database in a single table and references specialized tables when getting the actual content.

I'm not a fan of the idea of trying to tuck everything into a table as XML.  That could prove to be a performance and flexibility dog over time.

Comment: That does ideally sound the best, but the benefit of using XML is that you can create new content types without needing to create new tables.

I'm thinking the XML hit might not be too bad. The data is only read when the full row is requested, and only written infrequently, so it wouldn't be too slow with maybe two or three dozen fields max - probably closer to a half dozen in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have different tables for each type of content? News, blog, etc.  It seems to me that would be the best and easiest to use option.

Comment: That's what I usually do, but things like tagging become a little more complex than they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Different tables for different types of content.  If you ever need to add a new content type or additional features to an existing content type you don't have to worry about breaking the world while you do it.